# Transfer money from stripe to bank account

Tags: stripe-payments

I have application in app(ios and android) for gaming. User will pay the money to admin's stripe account for playing. A game can be played by two users. The winning user will get money as prize and it will show in user's wallet in the app.

Now user can withdraw that money from that wallet to his bank account.

Please help.

Comment: You'd want to have a look at Stripe's Connect product. Each user you wanted to pay out would need to have a Stripe Account https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts -- I might also email Stripe and see if their use case is something they can support. https://stripe.com/us/restricted-businesses

Comment: Can I link stripe and plaid with API? Or I have to do it by manually?

Comment: For collecting + debiting customer's accounts using ACH, yes, you can use Plaid. https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid

Answer (score 0):

I had the same scenario.
I send mail to support team and they said currently stripe do not support direct transfer but may be in future.
You can transfer amount to those user who are registered with you as a stripe connect user and for that you have to force user to register on stripe.